# How can I scp files during a systemd shutdown?

Tags: ssh, rhel, systemd

My system has certain files which I need to transfer using scp as a node is shutting down.

I have a systemd service file which looks like this.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Transfer Service
After=multi-user.target sockets.target network.target auditd.service \
    timers.target sshd.socket sshd@.service systemd-user-sessions.service \
    user@0.service system-sysctl.service paths.target swap.target \
    network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo "My Transfer Service"
ExecStop=/custom/dir/transfer.bash
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutStopSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target timers.target
```

The transfer script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

scp -r /important/dir otheruser@target_node:~/
if [ "$?" != "0" ]
then
    echo "ERROR `date`: Failure to transfer" >> transfer_log
    exit 1
fi

echo "SUCCESS `date`" >> transfer_log
```

The ssh keys are set up correctly between *this* system's root user and the other system's "other_user". This scp does not require a password.

The transfer succeeds if I run the script standalone as root user.

The transfer also succeeds if I use the command `systemctl stop my-transfer`

The transfer will fail when I call `reboot`. When I log back in I see error messages in my log.

How can I use systemd to scp files during a shutdown? (This is a RedHat distro)

Edit:

The error that scp gives me is

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
lost connection
```

My serial output up until the transfer service stops

```
         Stopping Load/Save Random Seed...
         Stopping Load/Save Screen Backlight...ness of backlight:acpi_video0...
[  OK  ] Stopped target System Time Synchr[  OK  ] Stopped Session c5 of user r.
         Stopping My-Transfer Service...
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Time Synchroni[  OK  ] Stopped Serial Getty on ttyS0.
[  OK  ] Stopped Load/Save Random Seed.
[  OK  ] Stopped Load/Save Screen Backlight ...htness of backlight:acpi_video0.
[  OK  ] Stopped My-Transfer Service.
```

**Update**

The transfer succeeds on shutdown if a regular `cp` command is used. That doesn't fix my problem, but it does prove the error is definitely related to scp somehow.

The command `systemctl status my-transfer-service` shows my service is **active (exited)**. The script `transfer.bash` is also usually run by crond at various intervals during system operation. Could it be that cron is attempting to run its jobs at shutdown as well?

Comment: Possibly you want `network-online.target` (see `man 7 systemd.special`). But other than that, what error messages are you getting? The journal should capture stderr.

Comment: The error from scp that is get is `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` then the next line is `lost connection`

Comment: There is a line above my transfer's `Stopped` message in the shutdown sequce which reads `Stopped User Manager for UID 0`. Does that affect root's ssh keys?

Comment: sounds like the network is being taken down during your script, did network-online.target work?

Comment: Not quite. I'll edit the question's sample code and include the scp error I see with it

Comment: I notice you have `TimeoutStopSec=0`. Is this supposed to be `=infinity`? Perhaps you should try an explicit long time or the default 90 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Missing from your `[Unit]` is the magic line:

```
Conflicts=reboot.target
```

This should cause your stop script to be called before the reboot service can be started and the network dies.

Comment: I have not tried that. I will try it first thing on Monday

Comment: No dice. I think a `conflicts reboot` is probably like `conflilcts shutdown`; it's probably like an implicit dependency systemd would otherwise automatically add by default just to ensure the service stops on its own terms before the system powers off. This would be very late in the shutdown.

Comment: Did you enable and start the service, as the conflict will have no effect unless the service is actually "running".

Comment: systemctl shows it as active(exited). I know the service is running though; the error log dates correspond with my shutdown times. The script this service calls is usually called via crond every so often while the system is running though. Does crond fire off all its jobs one last time as the system is shutting down?

Comment: I dont think crond should do anything special. Note, if you are doing shutdown rather than reboot you need to list it: `Conflicts=reboot.target shutdown.target`

Comment: I am using reboot 99% of the time so the `Conflicts=reboot` is still my correct case I think

Answer (score 1):

I'll post this as an answer since it's what I did, and I found it to be much easier than trying to shove down every systemd process I could find.

I created a special shutdown script to perform the actions before executing either reboot or shutdown. I aliased shutdown to `sudo /my/special/script.sh`, and followed a similar pattern for reboot , as well as aliasing `alias sudo = 'sudo '`. I also had to add this script to the sudoers files for the appropriate users.